# Android: Enable Firebase DebugView without ADB

Tags: android, firebase, adb, firebase-analytics

We are using Firebase DebugView and currently we enable it via ADB, as described in [the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/debugview#android):

```
adb shell setprop debug.firebase.analytics.app package_name
```

This works fine but it is a little bit tedious for QA since many of them do not have ADB installed.

First idea was to set the property via System.setProperty() but I realised quickly that this will not work, its scope is limited to my app.

Do you have any idea how to enable it programatically or part of the delivery process?
I mean, is there a way to run some extra ADB commands when delivering an APP via Firebase App Tester?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apps can't run adb commands or set system properties.  That would be a security problem.

Analytics debug view is only meant for use during development and testing when you control the device being used to test.  It's not meant to be used with apps that get published to stores or distribution services.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer!

Comment: But what about allow it by not set system property, but by code? We releases apps to Firebase app tester for our QA, but we are not able to allow in this release DebugView by switch/checkbox in app. Our QA / Marketing team which need validate GA4 events does not have technical skills like install and use ADB, so they can't validate that events are ok. iOS has ability enable DebugView in build time, but not Android...